# pageBlockTable not rendering after delete link

Tags: visualforce, rerender

[image]

I feel like I've wasted enough time tracking it down.Pretty simple thing.

I have a pageBlockTable. One of the links in it, lets me delete that row. After the row is deleted the table should be rerendered so you can see that it has been removed. Currently the record DOES get deleted, but the table is not rerendered. I tried putting it in an output panel and no luck there. I was wondering if maybe the table is reloading before the record is actually deleteed, causing a 'race' condition type of situation? Anyway, below is the code. Feel free to point out what I am doing wrong.Thanks in advance

```
 <apex:page controller="PagingTasksController1">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Tasks" id="pgBlock">
            <apex:inputText id="searchBox" value="{!searchText}"/>
              <apex:commandButton value="Search" reRender="pgTable,pgBlock" action="{!findTasks}"/>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Tasks}" var="tsk" id="pgTable" >
          <apex:column >
              <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Task.Delete, tsk.id,['retURL'='/apex/New_Test_task_Assignment'])}" >Delete</apex:outputLink>
        </apex:column>

      <apex:column headerValue="Subject">
            <apex:outputField value="{!tsk.Subject}"/>
       </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Status">
             <apex:outputField value="{!tsk.Status}"/>
        </apex:column>
       <apex:column headerValue="Priority">
         <apex:outputField value="{!tsk.Priority}"/>
    </apex:column>
      <apex:column headerValue="OwnerId">
          <apex:outputField value="{!tsk.OwnerId}"/>
      </apex:column>
   </apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
 <apex:enhancedlist type="Activity" height="800" rowsPerPage="50" customizable="False"/>
   </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not re-rendering the table when you click the outputlink. Since the `apex:outputlink` component doesn't support the `rerender` attribute, I would use `apex:commandLink` instead, and then add `rerender="pgBlock"` - [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_commandLink.htm)

Comment: Pic attached for better understanding. It is working with apex:commandLink but it shows the "Subject" field in URL format which should not be.

Comment: @james Please be clearer about what the remaining problem (if any) is. The screen shot looks fine to me.

Comment: The problem is if i use apex:commandLink then it displays me the "Subject" field in the URL format. The pic attached shown has used apex:outputlink to get this done.So,it's simply that after deleting the record , the pageblocktable is not rendering and the row too gets deleted.So how do i achieve it ??

Comment: What do you mean by displaying the subject in the URL format? We're not touching the subject here, only the Action column...

Comment: @Bachovski  What is happening is with me adding apex:commandLink ,the row is not getting deleted.